# Array behave differently in the main function and outside the main function?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to see what will happen when I put some data more than the array can hold in the array. But things differ when I declare the array in the main function and outside the function.

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char arr[5]="lala";     //I declare the array of 5 outside the main function

 int main()
{
    scanf("%5s",arr);       //first I input the data
    printf("%p\n",arr);     //the address of the array
    printf("%s\n",arr);     //the contents of the array

    char* ptr=arr+5;        
    printf("%p\n",ptr);     //the address right after the array
    printf("%s\n",ptr);     //the contents after the array's scope

    return 0;
}
```

And the result of this program is:

```
whatisyourname     //this is my input, and the output is below
00409000
whati
00409005
                //notice that there is a newline here
```

So I change the program a little bit, just putting the declaration of the array inside the main program

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
{
    char arr[5]="lala";     //I declare the array here now
    scanf("%5s",arr);       
    printf("%p\n",arr);     
    printf("%s\n",arr);     

    char* ptr=arr+5;        
    printf("%p\n",ptr);    
    printf("%s\n",ptr);     

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is differnt:

```
whatisyourname    //my input
0028ff37
whati
0028ff3c    
<  (             //this is where the different happen
```

I know this maybe because that one is in the stack and the other is in the heap or so.  But I wonder, will the result be the same everytime?  I have do some test on other compiler. The result is the same for the **first program**. But I wonder if it is just so happen, arbitrarily.

And question two is: if it is not arbitrary, then why would the compile truncate the data I input before putting in in the array in the first program, but not in the second program.

Comment: In both cases you are playing around with undefined behavior, maybe it just so happens that in the first example it is more likely that there is a 0 after the array, but you could get any output in either case

Comment: Accessing `arr+5` (read or write) leads to undefined behavior. In addition, I would carefully make sure that `scanf("%5s",arr)` "takes care" of the null-character, or else you've got yourself yet another cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: If you're trying to put more data than array can handle, you're de facto modifying memory that could be used by other variables. So if you'd have more variables, you'd notice that some of them suddenly might be changed to different values. Might, because it all depends on the order of memory that the code produced by the compiler is using, as well as the layout of program binary set up by the operating system, etc. You must not depend on anything you observe during tests like that, because like everyone already said, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: If the answer below solves your problem, please accept it by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer. If you still have some problem, please edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of your examples, you are trying to access the content after the end of the array `arr`, which is undefined behavior.

> I know this maybe because that one is in the stack and the other is in the heap or so.

Not really, in the second example, `arr` is in the stack, while in the first example, `arr` is in the static storage, not the heap.

> But I wonder, will the result be the same everytime?

No, as explained, it's undefined behavior, the result could be anything.

Comment: But where is the other **syourname** character? Shouldn't I see it after the array? Are they truncated automatically?

Comment: @walkerlala You are using `"%5s"` format specifier, which means only 5 characters are read. Note that `arr` doens't have enough space for it because the null terminator needs one extra character.